# Disable, ideally permanently, the "small shrunken window" effect new to MacOS 13, when, you try to move a window by grabbing the frame. SCREENSHOT!

Tags: macos, ventura

On the latest MacOS. I have additional displays connected if it matters.

Say you grab the top of any window of any app, so as to move the window.

In many cases the overall window becomes, that is to say zooms down in size, to a "large icon" of the window (say, a couple inches square) which you then move. (When you let go, the window again becomes the normal size.)

- What, specifically, is the trigger for this happening?

I have not been able to work out exactly what it is - moving your hand fast? grabbing a particular spot?  IDK.

More importantly,

- how to absolutely, completely, eliminate this behavior?

#### CAPTURED!

[image]

I was moving a normal-size *Pages* window and it happened.

I used keystroke to capture all displays, and, it is shown.

Could it be something only affecting Pages?

I can't quite repro exactly what makes it happen / not happen. (Perhaps, which part of the top bar of the Pages window?)

Note that the screen cap does not show my cursor-mouse, but, it was pointing at / holding right in the CENTER of the mystery mini-ghost window.

Comment: Just chiming in to say I've never observed this behavior happening myself, except for dragging Safari tabs around - which isn't new in Ventura

Comment: Are you sure you haven't installed some third-party tool for managing windows, like Moom, Rectangle, BetterSnapTool, etc? Or are you perhaps activating Mission Control?

Comment: Hmm, I do actually use Moom, but, I have never seen this behavior having used Moom for 10? 15? yrs.  It's possible I unwittingly have missioncontrol activated, I will try to figure that out.  TY

Comment: I'll get a video of it ...

Comment: I'm 99.99% certain Moom has no such feature (unless there's a bug in Moom that interacts w/ Ventura) but I have anyway eliminated Moom as a test.  TY

Comment: I've seen this, or similar on the odd occasion; very rarely though.  Maybe 4 or 5 times since Ventura came out.

Comment: @Redarm - right, it's a real thing...

Comment: I GOT A SCREEN SHOT

Comment: I see this behavior *all the time* in Safari when dragging a tab to create a new window. I would bet that this is Apple's "create a new window" animation that is baked into the OS. I've never seen anything that would change this behavior or remove it.

Comment: resolved thanks to @Ezekiel , I put in an answer FYI

Comment: resolved thanks to @SteveChambers , I put in an answer FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved by @Ezekiel:

In fact. In Pages, it is possible to permanently turn off the feature via

View > Hide Tab Bar -> hide

#### Resolved:

It seems this is a new feature (?) on Pages, and/or, only on Pages in Ventura, and/or, perhaps other apps as well (only in Ventura?)

If your mouse hits basically the area shown here in red, it seems to apply the "small ghost window" logic.

If your mouse hits the usual header area (ie, green) then the window behaves normally.

[image]

With thanks to @Ezekiel and @SteveChambers who point out that Safari **TABS** have a behavior like this.

(I never use tabs in browsers, so, I had no clue about this.)

Exploring the behavior, there is possibly a bug in the Pages one, it seems to "not move immediately" for some reason (whereas it seems to work "immediately and properly" in Safari-tabs, but I don't know, because I'm not a tabs user and don't know the behavior over years).

I am fairly sure (but not certain) this change in Pages only happened when Ventura appeared, since, I use Pages and am aware of the updates to it.

I also think (but I'm not certain) the same seemingly new behavior also happens in other apps (I'm pretty sure I've been "annoyed by it" in other apps, not just Pages, since Ventura!) but I don't have the time to go through every app and try to figure it out!

As SteveChambers says it seems very unlikely there's a way to turn this off in Pages, if you were to want it turned off.  It would seem the only solution is to "avoid the red area", which is basically impossible for anyone with decades of finger memory using computers.

As I mention the particularly frustrating thing is as well as "making the mini window" it appears to be simply broken, it often just "doesn't move anywhere" when you grab that "mini title".  (Also, why anyway is there a mini-title?!  It's simply an echo of the actual title above it!)

That's it I guess...

Comment: You can hide the tab bar when there's only one tab, View > Hide Tab Bar. It will stay unless you have more than one tab in a window.

Comment: MY GOD !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Then what I saw is just similar, not the same.  I do use tabs extensively and do expect this behaviour when I drag a tab, but I did not expect it the 4 or 5 times I noticed it.

Comment: @Redarm - yes, for me there is something slightly "wrong" with the way it works in Pages, and indeed, some change was made (I guess in the recent version of Pages, or conceivably when the OS changed ..)